# extract a single text available in dropdown

Tags: jsoup

Is it possible to select a single text  that is available in list of drop down using selector?
something like:

```
 p > w|Sdt  > w|ListItem (with text value following)
```

from this use case I would like to get "Here is a Value1"

```
<p>
&nbsp; <w:Sdt DropDown="t" id="-537820932">
        <w:ListItem ListValue="SELECT ONE" DataValue="SELECT ONE"/>
        <w:ListItem ListValue="test1" DataValue="test1"/>
        <w:ListItem ListValue="test2" DataValue="test2"/>Here is a Value1
        <w:ListItem ListValue="test3" DataValue="test3"/>
        <w:ListItem ListValue="test4" DataValue="test4"/>
        </w:Sdt>
    <o:p/>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can utilize [`Node.nextSibling()`](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#nextSibling--) method. I've created an example based on your HTML with one small addition - I've added another text to show you what you have to take into account in such case.

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Node;

import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

final class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String html = "<p>\n" +
                "&nbsp; <w:Sdt DropDown=\"t\" id=\"-537820932\">\n" +
                "        <w:ListItem ListValue=\"SELECT ONE\" DataValue=\"SELECT ONE\"/>\n" +
                "        <w:ListItem ListValue=\"test1\" DataValue=\"test1\"/>\n" +
                "        <w:ListItem ListValue=\"test2\" DataValue=\"test2\"/>Here is a Value1\n" +
                "        <w:ListItem ListValue=\"test3\" DataValue=\"test3\"/>\n" +
                "        <w:ListItem ListValue=\"test4\" DataValue=\"test4\"/>Test\n" +
                "        </w:Sdt>\n" +
                "    <o:p/>\n" +
                "</p>";

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);

        Set<String> texts = doc.select("p > w|Sdt > w|ListItem")
                .stream()
                .map(Node::nextSibling)
                .map(Node::toString)
                .map(String::trim)
                .filter(el -> !el.isEmpty())
                .collect(Collectors.toSet());

        System.out.println(texts);
    }
}
```

As you can see we start with `p > w|Sdt > w|ListItem` selector that will catch all list items. Next we select next siblings of all elements, take their text representation and filter out all empty values, because list elements without any text next to them will return empty string. And eventually we collect all values to a set. Running this example will produce an output:

```
[Test, Here is a Value1]
```

If your case guarantees that there is only single text next to the list item, then you can change `.collect(Collectors.toSet())` with `.findFirst().orElse(null)`.

Here you can check live <kbd>[Demo](https://jdoodle.com/a/5E1)</kbd>

Comment: this is great, do you think it is possible to get the same solution with a selector expression?

for example: p > w|Sdt > w|ListItem -> next is not empty?

Comment: @user648026 I guess not. At least I couldn't get it working using single selector expression. The main problem is that the text you are trying to extract is outside any HTML tag. The equivalent would be something like this one `p > w|Sdt > w|ListItem + *:matchesOwn(.+)`, you can run it to see it does not work.